# How can you create a helm package on my CI from a chart without helm init? or access to a cluster

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to package a helm chart on my CI server without having to helm init

```
  docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/tmp/src/ -w /tmp/src/ alpine/helm helm package ./charts
  docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/tmp/src/ -w /tmp/src/ alpine/helm  helm init --client-only && helm package ./charts
```

The above do not work can anyone help! i thought this would be a common request the ability to create a helm package without the .kube folder or access to a cluster

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [helm-maven-plugin](https://github.com/kiwigrid/helm-maven-plugin)

Basically you can use Maven to get the same result, and should be able to do it from most CI software.